# Como chamar uma função em java script puro quando desmarcado e marcado um checkbox?

Tags: javascript, funções, checkbox, javascript-eventos, eventos

Como fazer isso em java script puro? pois há a necessidade de alterar os valores de um input quando o checkbox é marcado e desmarcado. Quero basicamente que quando for marcando os checkbox os valores vão somando e quando desmarcado subtraído.

```
<div id="opc1" class="form-group" style="">
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="1" name="opc1" type="checkbox" value="100">
    <span>100 personalizados</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="2" name="opc2" type="checkbox" value="10">
    <span>20 Centros de mesa com 2 Balões a gás em ca</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="3" name="opc3" type="checkbox" value="20">
    <span>Enchimento e orçamentação de 3000 balões</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="4" name="opc4" type="checkbox" value="30">
    <span>Bolo cenográfico de 3 andares</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="5" name="opc5" type="checkbox" value="40">
    <span>Cobertura Fotográfica</span>
</label><br>
```

Comment: editei novamente

Comment: O que seria esse `value="1-100.00"` no primeiro checkbox? Eu estou com a resposta pronta, só não publico por conta desse valor.

Comment: seria 100, já foi editado, desculpa pelo erro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primeiramente vamos adicionar uma tag para mostrar o resultado:**

```
<strong id="total">0</strong>
```

**Agora vamos para o javascript:**

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelector('#opc1')
      .querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var total = document.querySelector('#total');
Object.keys(checkboxes).map((key) => {
    checkboxes[key].addEventListener('change', function() {
        total.innerHTML = +total.innerHTML + (this.checked ? +this.value : -this.value);
    });
});
```

1. `var checkboxes = document.document.querySelector('#opc1').querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');` **->** Pega todos os checkbox que contém na div com ID *"opc1"*;
2. `var total = document.querySelector('#total')` **->** pega a tag com ID *"total"*;
3. `Object.keys(checkboxes).map((key) =>` **->** Como foi retornado um JSON em *checkboxes*, essa linha transforma as chaves do JSON em uma lista;
4. `checkboxes[key].addEventListener('change', function() {` **->** aqui ele fica escutando (*Listener*) se cada checkbox (*checkboxes[key]*) terá uma mudança (*change*);
5. `total.innerHTML = +total.innerHTML + (this.checked ? +this.value : -this.value)` **->** Se o checkbox estiver selecionado, ele irá somar o valor anterior com o novo, caso contrário irá diminuir.

Espero ter ajudado, bons estudos!

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementById('opc1')
 .querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var total = document.querySelector('#total');
Object.keys(checkboxes).map((key) => {
 checkboxes[key].addEventListener('change', function() {
  total.innerHTML = +total.innerHTML + (this.checked ? +this.value : -this.value);
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="opc1" class="form-group" style="">
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="1" name="opc1" type="checkbox" value="100">
    <span>100 personalizados</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="2" name="opc2" type="checkbox" value="10">
    <span>20 Centros de mesa com 2 Balões a gás em ca</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="3" name="opc3" type="checkbox" value="20">
    <span>Enchimento e orçamentação de 3000 balões</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="4" name="opc4" type="checkbox" value="30">
    <span>Bolo cenográfico de 3 andares</span>
</label><br>
<label class="d-inline">
    <input id="5" name="opc5" type="checkbox" value="40">
    <span>Cobertura Fotográfica</span>
</label><br>
<strong id="total">0</strong>
```